# there must be a better way to get average price in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i am trying to plot average price of volume, i am sure there is a a better and easier way,  so i would really appreciate someones help and to hear your ideas, probably dont have to mention that i am still learning :).

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="avg voulme", shorttitle="my volume", overlay=false, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
avglookback = input.int(defval=15, title="Volume lookback", minval=1)
average = math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15])

switch
avglookback==1 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1])
avglookback==2 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2])
avglookback==3 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3])
avglookback==4 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4])
avglookback==5 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5])
avglookback==6 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6])
avglookback==7 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7])
avglookback==8 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8])
avglookback==9 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9])
avglookback==10 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10])
avglookback==11 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11])
avglookback==12 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12])
avglookback==13 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13])
avglookback==14 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14])
avglookback==15 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15])
avglookback==16 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16])
avglookback==17 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17])
avglookback==18 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18])
avglookback==19 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19])
avglookback==20 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20])
avglookback==21 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21])
avglookback==22 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22])
avglookback==23 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23])
avglookback==24 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24])
avglookback==25 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25])
avglookback==26 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26])
avglookback==27 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27])
avglookback==28 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28])
avglookback==29 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29])
avglookback==30 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30])
avglookback==31 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31])
avglookback==32 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32])
avglookback==33 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33])
avglookback==34 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34])
avglookback==35 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35])
avglookback==36 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36])
avglookback==37 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37])
avglookback==38 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38])
avglookback==39 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39])
avglookback==40 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40])
avglookback==41 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41])
avglookback==42 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42])
avglookback==43 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43])
avglookback==44 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44])
avglookback==45 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44], volume[45])
avglookback==46 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44], volume[45], volume[46])
avglookback==47 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44], volume[45], volume[46], volume[47])
avglookback==48 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44], volume[45], volume[46], volume[47], volume[48])
avglookback==49 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44], volume[45], volume[46], volume[47], volume[48], volume[49])
avglookback==50 => average := math.avg(volume, volume[1], volume[2], volume[3], volume[4], volume[5], volume[6], volume[7], volume[8], volume[9], volume[10], volume[11], volume[12], volume[13], volume[14], volume[15], volume[16], volume[17], volume[18], volume[19], volume[20], volume[21], volume[22], volume[23], volume[24], volume[25], volume[26], volume[27], volume[28], volume[29], volume[30], volume[31], volume[32], volume[33], volume[34], volume[35], volume[36], volume[37], volume[38], volume[39], volume[40], volume[41], volume[42], volume[43], volume[44], volume[45], volume[46], volume[47], volume[48], volume[49], volume[50])


plot(volume, title="vol", color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(average, title="avg", color=color.purple,linewidth=2)
```

i tried checking on TV, and online but cant find answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. You can use a [simple moving average](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dsma) for that.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="avg voulme", shorttitle="my volume", overlay=false, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

var int avglookback = input.int(defval=15, title="Volume lookback", minval=1)

average = ta.sma(volume, avglookback)

plot(volume, title="vol", color=color.green,linewidth=2)
plot(average, title="avg", color=color.purple,linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i see there is a lot more learning for me :). Really appreciate your help